# Getting BaseMapToggle error from ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, legend, arcgis-online-basemaps

I'm having a problem with my Web Application.
I try to fit in a legend and a BasemapToggle but it doesn't seem to work.

My Code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/dojo/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/js/esri/css/esri.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://192.168.163.129:6080/arcgis/rest/static/jsapi.css">

<script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.8/"></script>

<script>
var map;
require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/dijit/Legend",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "dojo/_base/array", 
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
    "dojo/domReady!",
    ],
function(Map, Legend, arrayUtils, BasemapGallery, arcgisUtils, parser) 
    {
    parser.parse();
    map = new esri.Map("map", {basemap: "topo", center: [10.8, 48.55], zoom: 9});
    
    var raum = new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://192.168.163.129:6080/arcgis/rest/services/Masterarbeit/MapServer", {opacity: 0.85});
    map.addLayer(raum);
    
    dojo.connect(map, 'onLayersAddResult', function(results){
        var layerInfo = new esri/dijit/Legend({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: {layer:raum, title:"Raumkategorien"},
                arrangement:esri/dijit/Legend/ALIGN_LEFT
        }, "legendDiv");
        layerInfo.startup();
    });
 
    
    var basemapGallery = new BasemapGallery({
        showArcGISBasemaps: true,
        map: map
    }, "basemapGallery");
    basemapGallery.startup();
    
    
    });
</script> 
</head> 
<body class="tundra"> 
<div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design:'headline', gutters:true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0;"> 
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'top'" id="navtable" style="background-image:url(http://192.168.163.129/Energiewende/master_1.png); width: 100%; height: 100px; z-index: 0"> 
        <div style="float:left;" id="breadcrumbs"><font color="white" face="Helvetica" size="6">Test Viewer</font><br><font color="white" face="Helvetica">Name here</font></div> 
        <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; right:10px" id="help"><a href="http://www.geo.uni-augsburg.de" target="_blank"><img src="IGUA-RGB_200x126.jpg" width="134" height="80" alt="Institut für Geographie - Universitaet Augsburg"></a></div> 
    </div> 
    <div id="leftPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'left'" style="width:15%">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/AccordionContainer">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" id="legendPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Legende', selected:true">
                <div id="legendDiv"></div>
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="title:'Tools here!'">Tools here!
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'" style="padding:0">
        <!--<div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:10px">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit/TitlePane" data-dojo-props="title:'Switch Basemap', closable:false,  open:false">
                <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" style="width:380px; height:280px; overflow:auto;">
                    <div id="basemapGallery" ></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>-->
    </div> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

So, if I'm using this code i get this result:
[image]

There's no content showing up in the LegendPane.
And if i undo the uncommented -part for the BasemapToggle it looks like this:

[image]

Does someone might have a hint or an answer for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using AMD, the order of the arguments in the function have to match how the modules are loaded. You have several out of order

```
require([
    "esri/map", 
    "esri/dijit/Legend",
    "esri/dijit/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/arcgis/utils",
    "dojo/_base/array", 
    "dojo/parser",
    "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", 
    "dijit/layout/ContentPane", 
    "dijit/layout/AccordionContainer", 
    "dojo/domReady!",
],
function(Map, Legend, BasemapGallery, arcgisUtils, arrayUtils, parser)
```

Take a look at this [blog posting](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2013/10/14/the-abcs-of-amd/) for more information

Comment: Thanks for your correction. That already helped for the BasemapGallery, but my legend doesn't work at all. Is there maybe an error in the code for loading the legend?

Comment: I couldn't get your code working, but made something similar: http://jsbin.com/mupir/1/edit?html,output

Comment: that's just fine. thank you very much. i added the part with legendLayers.push in my code and it works just fine

Comment: Glad to hear that. You should mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Realized this is really old, but you could try something like this for those looking at this now.

```
// Creates the Legend from list of Feature Classes shown on map
  //  Dynamically changes depening on scale and what features are visible
  map.on("layers-add-result", function(evt) {
    var layerInfo = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(layer, index) {
      return {
        layer: layer.layer,
        title: layer.layer.name
        };
      });
      if (layerInfo.length > 0) {
        var legendDijit = new Legend({
          map: map,
          layerInfos: layerInfo
          }, "legendDiv");
        legendDijit.startup();
      }
  });
```